# Wrong title in the browser tab R Shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I am getting my title in the browsers tab to be named the following:

```
    <div> <img src="pd_logo.jpg" align="left"/> Model </div>
```

It is caused by the following code

```
    shinyUI(navbarPage(title=(div(img(src="logo.jpg", align = "left"), 
    " Model")), fluid = TRUE, ... ))
```

How to have a normal name in the browsers tab instead?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the `windowTitle` variable in `navbarPage` along with little raw HTML

```
 shinyUI(navbarPage(title=(div(img(src="logo.jpg", align = "left"), 
                          " Model")), 
               ,windowTitle = HTML("<title>Model</title> <link rel='icon' type='image/gif/png' href='logo.jpg'>")
               fluid = TRUE, ... ))
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the other answer leads to the entire code inside the HTML function to be inside the browser tab i.e. `<title>Model</title> <link rel='icon' type='image/gif/png' href='logo.jpg'>`. In fact, now you just need to set `windowTitle` to a string as below:

```r
title = div(img(src="logo.png",height=46,width=46),align="left"),

windowTitle = "Your title",
```

and the logo shows automatically before "Your title".

Modification: Locally this works fine, but I found that when I deploy my app to shinyapps.io, the icon in the browser tab is gone. Here is the fix:

```r
  title = div(img(src="logo.png",height=46,width=46),align="left"),
  
  windowTitle = "Your title",
  
  tags$head(HTML("<link rel='icon' type='png' href='logo.png'>")),
```